# How do I set "Delay Click" in Ubuntu?

Tags: mouse, accessibility

I installed ubuntu for my friend who has neuropathy, and it makes it hard for him to click, and he often will accidentally click as well.

I want to make it so that when he clicks, he has to hold down on the mouse button for it to register; how do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called [mousetweaks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/mousetweaks.1.html) that provides tools for manipulating the mouse setting. This is from the [proposal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accessibility/Specs/MouseTweaks):

> **Delay-click**
>
> Click and hold the left mouse button to simulate clicking the right mouse button. Holding the left button for n seconds without moving the cursor more than x pixels initiates a right click+hold. Releasing the left button also releases the simulated right hold. Useful in using the context menu with only one mouse button.
>
> A configuration panel should present the following settings: Enable, time delay.

This from the launchpad page:

> The main application provides dwell-clicking which simulates different mouse clicks without using physical buttons **and a delay-click feature** which opens context menus by holding the left mouse button for a specified amount of time.

---

If this does not provide what you need (it is from 2007...) you could file a feature request.